# Can we use pg-query-stream with pg-promise in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, pg, pg-promise

I want to use `pg-query-stream` with `pg-promise`. Is there any chance that we can use both together? I know it can be used with `pg`.

Comment: Can you accept the answer I provided? It's been awhile.

Answer (score 0):

It is within [streaming examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#streaming) in documentation:

```
import QueryStream from 'pg-query-stream';
import JSONStream from 'JSONStream';

const qs = new QueryStream('SELECT * FROM my_table');

await db.stream(qs, s => {
    s.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(process.stdout);
});
//=> resolves with: {processed, duration}
```

**UPDATE**

In many cases, use of [pg-iterator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-iterator) can be a better solution, that's why I implemented it.

In `pg-promise`, the database object exposes the pool via `db.$pool`, which we can use for this:

```
import {QueryIterablePool} from 'pg-iterator';

const q = new QueryIterablePool(db.$pool); // reuse pg-promise pool object

const i = q.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [123]);

for await(const u of i) {
    console.log(u); // output each row
}
```